# Trying to get a good order with quiz system

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, while-loop

I am trying to make a quiz system but it outputs:

```
Question1
Answer1
Question1
Answer2
```

And so on.. instead of

```
Question1
Answer1
Answer2
... and so on
```

How can I fix that?

Code:

```
$question = mysql_query("SELECT questions.*, answers.* FROM questions inner join answers on questions.id=answers.question_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($question))
{
    echo $row['question'].'<br />' .$row['answer'].'<br />';            
}
```

Comment: What are you selecting all the values in both questions and answers tables in select query, you can just select questions and answers?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, please use PDO or either mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 3):

Fix your WHILE LOOP. It will always print the question and the answer. Quick fix would look something like this:

```
$previousQuestion = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($question))
{
    if($row['question'] !== $previousQuestion) {
        echo $row['question'].'<br />';
    }

    echo $row['answer'].'<br />';

    $previousQuestion = $row['question'];
}
```

The syntax can be simplified in other ways, but this will work. Basically, since there is a one to many relationship between a question and its answers, only print the question if it is not the same as the previous row's question.

Comment: I now see just the answers, no output for the questions.

Comment: Oh shoot, I see what you mean now. Actually you should see the first question only. Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant so my answer is incorrect. Gimme a second to fix it.

Comment: @MichaelNaidis See my edit. I don't have time to test it out but the syntax should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in MySQL only, you can do so:

```
SELECT question AS 'Question And Its Answers'
FROM
(
  SELECT 0 AS Type, id, question FROM questions 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, question_id, answer FROM answers 
) t
ORDER BY id, Type;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbb48/7)

This will give you:

```
| QUESTION AND ITS ANSWERS |
----------------------------
|                question1 |
|                      eee |
|                       dd |
|                      dsd |
|                question2 |
|                       df |
|                       fd |
|                question3 |
|                      ans |
|                       dd |
|                       ad |
```